# How to get unique names from a column of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column (in a dataframe) that contains multiple city names and I need to know the unique name of cities.

```
        city
0      Dallas,Columbus,Portland,LasVegas
1      Columbus,Dallas,LasVegas
2      Dallas
3      Portland,Columbus,LosAngeles
4      Columbus
```

I want to obtain a list of cities like that: Dallas,Columbus,Portland,LasVegas,LosAngeles.

I tried to use countVectorize function and pandas unique() method but I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.city.str.split(",").explode().unique().tolist()
```

`split` the strings over `","` which will give a `list` in each row. Then `explode` those lists to get a long series where each row has now one city name. Then take `unique` on them to get the distinct city names. Finally convert `tolist` to get:

```
['Dallas', 'Columbus', 'Portland', 'LasVegas', 'LosAngeles']
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `str.split` with `.stack()` and `unique`

```
df['city'].str.split(',',expand=True).stack().unique()

array(['Dallas', 'Columbus', 'Portland', 'LasVegas', 'LosAngeles'],
      dtype=object)
```